# ManagedBean accessing another ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I'm probably really close to the solution but I'm new with JSF and I don't see my mistake.
I have a first SessionScoped Managed Bean that represents Business information (address, website, ...)

```
@Named(value = "businessController")
@SessionScoped
public class BusinessController implements Serializable {
    private Business current;
    @EJB private BusinessFacade ejbFacade;
    ....
```

I have a second SessionScoped Managed Bean that represents the logged in user

```
@Named(value = "loginController")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {

    private Login current;
    @EJB
    private LoginFacade ejbFacade;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{businessController}")
    private BusinessController businessController;

    public BusinessController getBusinessController() {
        return businessController;
    }

    public void setBusinessController(BusinessController businessController) {
        this.businessController = businessController;
    }
```

When a user logs in, I set the current attribute from the loginController
Depending on this current user, I want to set the business attribute from the businessController :

```
businessController.setCurrent(current.getBusiness());
```

My problem is that the businessController attribute is null !

I use NetBeans 7.0.1 and GlassFish 3.1
In debug mode, I can see a viewId variable with the value

```
>No current context (stack frame)<
```

Unfortunately it doesn't ring any bell to me.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing JSF managed beans with CDI managed beans.

Your BusinessController is annotated with the CDI annotaion `@Named` but gets injected with the `@ManagedProperty` annotation (from JSF). CDI managed beans need to be injected with `@Inject`. No getter or setter needed in this case. If you tend to use CDI, make sure that you import the correct `@SessionScoped`:

> CDI: javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
>
> JSF: javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped

Try the following (After making sure to have the correct scope class imported):

```
 @Inject private BusinessController businessController;
```